# Video playback from windows share(JAVA)

Tags: java, media, javafx, smb, jcifs

i need to play video file from windows share. I'am using jcifs for access to share with predefined login and password.

All the media players that I've tried(vlcj, javaFX media package) can play videos only by URI or URL and not supports smb protocol, at the other hand jcifs supports smb but cannot create URI for this file.

Is there a java media player implementaiton what supports playing from input stream?

If you can suggest adobe flash( or air) solution for this task, it will be great!

Thanks, Alexey.

Answer (score -1):

jcifs has a protocol handler that should allow you to create urls like: smb://SERVER/share/file